# Simple html dom parser table

Tags: php

Im using [Simple HTML Dom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) to parse the data into my own php script, I need to get the text inside the td, only one td of more in the table. [Website](https://rub.currencyrate.today/) from where I try to parse the table->td. Specifically, I need the first USD td.

The result must be

> $ 0.0137

Source php:

```
<?php
  include('../simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = file_get_html('https://rub.currencyrate.today/'); 
   foreach($html->find('table') as $e){
      foreach($e->find('td',0) as $f){
      echo strip_tags($f->innertext) . '<br>';
     }
   }
?>
```

This code displays result

> ₽ 1 $ 0.0137 € 0.0115 £ 0.00988 ¥ 0.0884 Ƀ 0.00000040

I've tried several ways to get that but i've fail in each and everyone of them. Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the second `<td>` in the first `<table>`.

Therefore there is no need to iterate (`foreach`) over all tables, and iterating over the first `<td>` is even wrong (if you check the error log, it will show you that already).

Lets do *first* table, *second* table-data, the numbers in [`find()`](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom/find/) are zero-based:

```php
$dollar = $html->find('table', 0)->find('td', 1)->innertext();
```

For your output take care to properly encode as HTML, [`strip_tags`](https://php.net/strip_tags) is not of much use there, you want just the HTML characters properly encoded with [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) (something `strip_tags` is not even capable of):

```php
echo htmlspecialchars($dollar, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5), '<br>';
```

> $ 0.0137

**A few further notes:**

- run with simplehtmldom 2.0-RC2: the version you use might have bugs. I could not fully reproduce your output with that version (but the traversal was wrong anyway)
- you should allow yourself the "luxury" to be able to see errors more prominently on your development box.
- take care encoding HTML output properly.
- the closing `?>` php tag is not necessary at the end of file, leave it out before it causes problems.
- last but not least if you allow me the remark: simplehtmldom is really old. you may consider at some time to make use of the [`DOMDocument`](https://php.net/DOMDocument) class which is from the *dom* PHP extension and use it together with the other *xml* PHP extensions (simplexml, xmlreader etc.).

**Example in full:**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

include __DIR__ . '/../simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://rub.currencyrate.today/');

$dollar = $html->find('table', 0)->find('td', 1)->innertext();
echo htmlspecialchars($dollar, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5), '<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the cod and suggestions, you helped me a lot. In my free time I will learn something other than html